# Bitcoin v23 is 10 times slower than v22 on macos for basic regtest tests

Tags: bitcoind, performance

This is how I start the node (I always start it from a clean state):

```
rm -rf /tmp/regtest1/bitcoind
mkdir -p /tmp/regtest1/bitcoind


#/Applications/Bitcoin\ Core\ 22.app/Contents/MacOS/Bitcoin-Qt \
/Applications/Bitcoin-Qt.app/Contents/MacOS/Bitcoin-Qt \
  -datadir=/tmp/regtest1/bitcoind \
  -regtest \
  -server \
  -txindex \
  -fallbackfee=0.0002 \
  -zmqpubhashtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:30001 \
  -zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:30001
```

Then I create a wallet and mine some blocks:

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest -datadir=/tmp/regtest1/bitcoind createwallet farvault_tests
GEN_ADDRESS=$(bitcoin-cli -regtest -datadir=/tmp/regtest1/bitcoind getnewaddress)
bitcoin-cli -regtest -datadir=/tmp/regtest1/bitcoind generatetoaddress 101 $GEN_ADDRESS
```

For some reason the App [downloaded here (v22)](https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-22.0/bitcoin-22.0-osx-signed.dmg) is x10 faster than the one [downloaded here (v23)](https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-23.0/bitcoin-23.0-x86_64-apple-darwin.dmg).

The new address and the 101 blocks are created in under 2 secs on v22 while it takes 17 secs on v23.

I also compiled bitcoind 23 with these options:

```
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
cd bitcoin
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-hardening --with-gui=no
make
```

which provides also the same bad performance as the v23 downloaded App.

Do you have any idea why v22 would be so much faster? Any clues as to how I should address the issue?

My computer is a 2.8 GHz quad-core Intel Core i7 running Macos Big Sur.

**EDIT**: I upgraded to Monterey and nothing changed: v22 is 10x faster than v23.

I have not checked performance on testnet and mainnet. I'm mostly interested in running integration tests for a project and it looks like I cannot upgrade to the new version yet without solving this.

Comment: This is behavior I can reproduce on v22 and v23

Comment: Good sources say this is likely fixed by: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/25985

Comment: My results from running the PR, dramatic improvement on m1 mac: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/25985#issuecomment-1245942400

Comment: I’m voting to close because this isn't the right place for Bitcoin Core bug reports.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisStewart. I will do the tests and update the question with my findings. Ideally, the Pull Request should be accepted and then we could close this issue explaining there's a compilation flag that fixes this problem.